# Polarization of electric field and its effect on the Poynting vector

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, diffraction

To preface, I've little experience with optics. This is a very use-case specific project I'm undertaking. So, if there are any improvements in my method, I'd appreciate it!

I'm working with the vector Rayleigh-Sommerfeld integral to propagate polarized light incident on an aperture as dictated by diffraction theory. The goal is to eventually determine the flux of the Poynting vector through some observation surfaces.

\begin{equation}
E_x(x, y, z) = -\frac{1}{2\pi}\iint_A E_x(x', y', 0) \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \left(\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}\right)\mathrm{d}x' \mathrm{d}y'
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
E_y(x, y, z) = -\frac{1}{2\pi}\iint_A E_y(x', y', 0) \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \left(\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}\right)\mathrm{d}x' \mathrm{d}y'
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
E_z(x, y, z) = -\frac{1}{2\pi}\iint_A \left[E_x(x', y', 0) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}\right) + E_y (x, y, 0) \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}\right) \right]\mathrm{d}x' \mathrm{d}y'
\end{equation}

where $E_x$ and $E_y$ are the $x$ and $y$ components of the incident electric field over the aperture $A$, $r = \sqrt{(x-x')^2 + (y-y')^2 + z^2)}$.

- When considering the incident light to be linearly polarized in the $x$ direction and the wave traveling in the $z$ direction, the $y$ component of the $E$ field vanishes. So, at any 3D point in space, the resulting vector looks something like $[E_x, 0, E_z]$. Consequently, the B field looks like $[Ex, 0, Ez] \cdot [a, b, c] = aE_x + bE_y + cE_z = 0$. If the E-field exists in the $x-z$ plane, the B field must exist in the $y-z$ plane but removing $a$, we get $aE_x + bE_y + cE_z = bE_y + cE_z = 0$. Knowing that $E_y$ is zero, $c$ must be zero as well, leaving only one non-zero component, $b$. I've cross-producted $E$ and $B$, applying the constraint that the wave vector must have a strictly positive $z$ component, which yields $b = E_x$ up to some constant factor. The issue here is that the $y$ component of the Poynting vector then disappears, leaving me with something like $[S_x, 0, S_z]$. Does this make any sense? Every point in space has an associated Poynting vector but this lies strictly in the $x-z$ plane. Is there a fallacy in my working or is this just how the case is constructed for linearly polarized light? What other polarization should I consider?
- My second question is generally concerning spherical waves. Huygens suggests that every point on the wavefront acts as a new spherical wavelet. How does the E and B field behave in this case? I've used the auxiliary Green's function for spherical waves in my calculations.

Thank you for your time! If you have any clarifications, please let me know.